# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined - Error in chrome after successfully compiling

Tags: reactjs

I compiled a react code and it was showing **successful compiled** in my terminal but i don't know why **this error** is coming on chrome.

This is the code:

```
render() {
    const filteredRobots =this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
        return (robots.name.**includes**( this.state.serchfeild ))
    }) 

}
```

Comment: `robots` just does not have a `name` property - at least for one entry in `this.state.robots`

Comment: It looks like you may have meant to type `robot` instead of `robots` when accessing the name parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong variable name inside arrow function. You need to use `robot.name` instead of `robots.name`. Below is correct code:

```
render() {
    const filteredRobots =this.state.robots.filter(robot => {
        return (robot.name.includes( this.state.serchfeild ))
    })  
}
```